# How do I make my function work on negative numbers?

Tags: python, multiplication

```
repeat = "y"
while repeat == "y":
    #First get the two integers from the user
    a = int(input("Enter the first integer: "))
    b = int(input("Enter the second integer: "))
    #Start the answer with 0
    answer = 0

    print("A", "B")
    print("---")
    print(a, b)
    #run loop until b is not zero
    while b != 0: 
        #loop while 'b' is odd number
        if (b % 2 != 0):
            answer = answer + a 
            print(a*2, b//2) 
            a = a*2 #double every 'a' integers
            b = b//2 #halve the 'b' integers
        #loop while 'b' is even number
        elif (b % 2 == 0):
            print(a*2, b//2)
            a = a*2 #double every 'a' integers
            b = b//2 #halve the 'b' integers
    print("The product is {}.".format(answer))
    repeat = input("Would you like to repeat? (y/n)")
print("Goodbye!")
```

I am writing a program that uses Ancient Egyptian method to multiply. My program works for positive numbers but not negative. How do I fix  it so that if both inputted values of user are negative. My result should give the product of any two positive, negative or one negative and positive number. My current program gives the product for any two positive values, or negative `a` value and positive `b` value. However, when user enters a negative `b` value, it produces infinite outputs.

Comment: _I tried several ways but they don't work_ Saying "it doesn't work" is not enough to help us understand the problem.  If you're getting errors, or unexpected results, you have to show us, and explain how it's different from the results you wanted.

Comment: You need to explain what doesn't work. Add input, expected and actual results and stacktrace if you have an error.

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the floor division `b//2`, when `b` is negative the result will be the *lower* integer, so `-0.5` will be rounded to `-1`. To avoid it cast to an `int` a regular division `b = int(b / 2)`.

After removing duplicate code the `while` loop looks like that

```
while b != 0:
    if b % 2 != 0:
        answer = answer + a
    print(a * 2, int(b / 2))
    a = a * 2
    b = int(b / 2)
```

**Edit**

To get the correct sign you can check the expected sign after getting the numbers and multiple by 1 or -1 at the end. Since you only check `a` for the answer you need to work on a positive `a`

```
....
answer = 0
sign = 1 if a * b > 0 else -1
a = abs(a)

while b != 0:
    ....

print("The product is {}.".format(answer * sign))
```

Comment: Hello Guy! Thank you so much for your time and effort to help me. Your suggestion helped my program work better. The only problem now is that the output gives me wrong sign. For example, when the input is -6 and -7, the output comes back as -42 while it should be positive. Again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: It works with both positive and negative numbers. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!!

This is what the program returned when I used -2 on the second integer (**b**).

```
A B
---
1 -2
2 -1
4 -1
8 -1
16 -1
```

If you notice, B stays on -1, while A starts increasing *2 and it does indifinitely because the while loop doesn't break.
Let's look at the code

```
while b != 0: 
        #loop while 'b' is odd number
        if (b % 2 != 0):
            answer = answer + a 
            print(a*2, b//2) 
            a = a*2 #double every 'a' integers
            b = b//2 #halve the 'b' integers
        #loop while 'b' is even number
        elif (b % 2 == 0):
            print(a*2, b//2)
            a = a*2 #double every 'a' integers
            b = b//2 #halve the 'b' integers
```

So on the if section, you do a=a*2 and b=b//2 since b%2!=0 (-1%2 is -1). However, for the while to break, you need to get b=0, and you get that by doing b=b//2. The problem, as Guy said before, is that when you get b=-1 (as you saw on my example), doing -1//2 will give you -1, instead of the supposed 0 that you'll get if you do 1//2. Since you won't get b=0, the program never stops multiplying.

The solution is simple, as guy mentioned, use b=int(b/2)

**EDIT for the negative numbers**

The reason it gives you the wrong sign when you are using multiplication is this instruction

```
    while b != 0: 
        #loop while 'b' is odd number
        if (b % 2 != 0):
            answer = answer + a #<--------------- THE INSTRUCTION
            a = a*2 #double every 'a' integers
            # b = b//2 #halve the 'b' integers
            b = int(b/2)
            print(a, b)
```

```
answer = answer + a #<--------------- THE INSTRUCTION
```

since you get your answer by just adding up A, you will have these two wrong scenarios
----> a positive and b negative ->gives you positive (the sign of A) when it should be negative
----> a negative and b negative -> gives you negative (the sign of A) when it should be positive

I tried to find on google how you handled negative numbers with the egyptian method but i didn't find anything, so I guess you can handle that issue with whichever method you prefer.
An alternative to Guy method is multiplying the sign (1 or -1) to the result depending of b, not the multiplication

```
#------------------Your code-------------------------
    #Start the answer with 0
    answer = 0

    print("A", "B")
    print("---")
    print(a, b)
    #run loop until b is not zero

#------------------The fix proposed-------------------------
    #Start the answer with 0
    answer = 0
    sign = 1 if b > 0 else -1          #---------> the fix
    print("A", "B")
    print("---")
    print(a, b)
    #run loop until b is not zero
```

and at the end, you multiply the sign with the general answer

```
#------------------Your code-------------------------
    elif (b % 2 == 0):
            print(a*2, b//2)
            a = a*2 #double every 'a' integers
            b = b//2 #halve the 'b' integers
    print("The product is {}.".format(answer))
    repeat = input("Would you like to repeat? (y/n)")
print("Goodbye!")

#------------------The fix proposed-------------------------
    elif (b % 2 == 0):
            a = a*2 #double every 'a' integers
            b = int(b/2) #---->the previous fix to your first problem
            print(a,b)
            # b = b//2 #halve the 'b' integers
    answer=answer*sign   #---->The another fix: the multiplication i mentioned
    print("The product is {}.".format(answer))
    repeat = input("Would you like to repeat? (y/n)")
print("Goodbye!")
```

With that, you should have the signs working properly

btw, the reason I changed the print insruction that you used to just print (a,b) at the end of the operation of the if sentence is to avoid redundant operations on the program.

Comment: Hello Cushiro! Thank you so much for help and time. As I also commented to Guy, your suggestion helped me get the answer but it produces wrong sign. When I enter two negative numbers it produces a negative output while it should be positive.

Comment: Alright, I updated the answer. Thanks for your notice